# remove consecutive values in a data table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I am trying to remove consecutive values in a data table. So in this case I want to eliminate all rows of every variable if there are more than 2 zeros in column `a`. So I need something like a `maxgap` to define how much consecutive zeros are allowed for some flexibility.

Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2),
                 b = as.factor(c("x", "y", "x", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "y")),
                 c = c(2, 5, 1, 0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 4))
```

and the result looks like this:

```
dtRes <- data.table(a = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2),
                    b = as.factor(c("x", "y", "x", "y", "y")),
                    c = c(2, 5, 1, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rle` :

```
library(data.table)
dt[!with(rle(a == 0), rep(values * lengths > 2, lengths))]

#   a b c
#1: 1 x 2
#2: 2 y 5
#3: 1 x 1
#4: 1 y 3
#5: 2 y 4
```

Comment: your solution works great and is very fast! I did a benchmark on my data and it is about 15-20 times faster than solutions with the rleid function. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You van do:

```
library("data.table")

dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2),
                 b = as.factor(c("x", "y", "x", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "y")),
                 c = c(2, 5, 1, 0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 4))

dt[, v:=rleidv(a==0)][]
dt[, if (a[1]!=0 | .N<3) .SD, v]
# > dt[, if (a[1]!=0 | .N<3) .SD, v]
#    v a b c
# 1: 1 1 x 2
# 2: 1 2 y 5
# 3: 1 1 x 1
# 4: 3 1 y 3
# 5: 3 2 y 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
dt[dt[, rleid(a == 0) * (a != 0) > 0]]
#   a b c
#1: 1 x 2
#2: 2 y 5
#3: 1 x 1
#4: 1 y 3
#5: 2 y 4
```

---

Or with `.I`

```
dt[dt[, .I[!(all(a == 0) & .N > 2)], rleid(a == 0)]$V1]
#   a b c
#1: 1 x 2
#2: 2 y 5
#3: 1 x 1
#4: 1 y 3
#5: 2 y 4
```